# Радиокнопка в виде звёздочки

Tags: input, radio, fontawesome

Здравствуйте. У меня есть задача - стандартные кружки радиокнопки заменить на звёздочки(к примеру font-awesome) и при этом чтобы остался тот же функционал.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/wyxuB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793716/how-to-change-style-of-radio-and-checkbox-input

Answer (score 1):

Тем же способом, что обычно:

```css
label { display: block; cursor: pointer; }

input[type="radio"] { display: none; }
input[type="radio"] + .fa:before { content: "\f06e"; } /* fa-eye */
input[type="radio"]:checked + .fa:before { content: "\f2da"; } /* fa-eercast */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<label><input type=radio name=smth><span class="fa"></span> Way 1</label>
<label><input type=radio name=smth><span class="fa"></span> Way 2</label>
<label><input type=radio name=smth checked><span class="fa"></span> Way 3</label>
<label><input type=radio name=smth><span class="fa"></span> Way 4</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно положить в 2 раза больше иконок и отображать одну из них.
Но лучше сделать как в [соседнем ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676521/178988).

```css
label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="radio"] ~ .fa-eercast,
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .fa-eye{
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] ~ .fa-eye,
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .fa-eercast {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<label><input type=radio name=smth><span class="fa fa-eye"></span><span class="fa fa-eercast"></span> Way 1</label>
<label><input type=radio name=smth><span class="fa fa-eye"></span><span class="fa fa-eercast"></span> Way 2</label>
<label><input type=radio name=smth checked><span class="fa fa-eye"></span><span class="fa fa-eercast"></span> Way 3</label>
<label><input type=radio name=smth><span class="fa fa-eye"></span><span class="fa fa-eercast"></span> Way 4</label>
```